# Numpy correlate-underlying code

Tags: python, numpy

What is the underlying python code of numpy.correlate?
I am trying to understand the logic of cross correlation. the underlying python code will be of great help.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html, this just gives the info about numpy.correlate. I am looking for the code running behind this method

Comment: What's wrong with the linked [Source]?

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L910-L975 This is the link to the source. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

All the code is somewhere on your system, you just need to find where.
If you're using `ipython`, the help command (`numpy.correlate?`) includes the filepath (on the second line from the end). 
On my system it's "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py
"
If you're not using `ipython`, `numpy.__file__` will give you a path to the installation directory for the module, and you'll have to look around a bit.
The module name given by `help(numpy.correlate)` will give some hints.

However, once you find the file you will see that numpy.correlate only does the following:

```
mode = _mode_from_name(mode)
return multiarray.correlate2(a, v, mode)
```

That is a compiled function, so it's a little harder to find.
You can view the file [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/30d8feec54abc180979a7db8df07150cfae5201f/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c), the main function is defined beginning on line 1353, and the actual algorithm begins on line 1190.
This is fairly optimized code, so it's doing quite a bit more than what is necessary for simple correlation: handling datatypes, multi-threading, and error handling.

If you just want to understand the general principles rather than specifics of what python is doing, I would recommend starting with a more [basic explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation).  Numeric operations such as correlation are very well defined, and `numpy` rarely does anything different from the standard definitions.